# Motion sensor light sqitch

Tags: switch, light

Replacing single pole light switch with a new  sensor light switch the new switch requires a neutral wire witch my old switch does not have... In the box where the switch is I have 3 wires copper.. black..white... The white wire is the hot wire... The pic shows the wiring at the light do I have a neutral at the light if so how can I get a neutral wire to the switch ? Thanks for your help... What you can not see in the pic is the copper wires they was not long enough to come out of ceiling....

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. A picture of the box and its wires would be extremely helpful, as would cleaning up your text (sentences make things readable). Thanks.

Comment: Where's the pic? If you have power and switched power at the switch, then no you can't use your new switch. You would have to run a new set of wires to the switch box and re-wire your ceiling box.